# Laravel validation - input must be one of items in array

Tags: validation, laravel, laravel-5

Is there a built in validator in Laravel 5 that checks if value is in array of my whitelisted values sort of speak.. Something like:

```
$rules = [
    'field_name' => "required|in_array('yes', 'no', 'maybe')",
];
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

There's [`in`](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#rule-in)

```
$rules = [
    'field_name' => "required|in:yes,no,maybe",
];
```

Comment: What about when the values you are checking against contain commas?

Answer (score 8):

Laravel 5.7

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

Validator::make($data, [
    'field_name' => [
        'required',
        Rule::in(['yes', 'no', 'maybe']),
    ],
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to this one, I needed a validation if `filed_name` starts with one of the items from the array, so you can use `starts_with` in the same manner

```php
$rules = [
    'field_name' => "required|starts_with:foo,bar",
];
```