# Laravel 5 array validation

Tags: arrays, validation, laravel-5, html-select

In laravel 5 how do i validate an array to check if at least one value is selected - the following doesn't work?

```
'user_list[]'  => 'array|min:1',

{{ Form::select('user_list[]', $users, null , ['multiple' => 'multiple']) }}
```

Comment: Duplicate question. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30616622/laravel-validation-input-must-be-one-of-items-in-array

Comment: It's not a duplicate question. This is totally different question to what you have linked. I'm asking how to check if at least one item has been selected. Your linked question is asking if a value selected exist in array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

fixed by changing the field name in the rules array as follows and by adding a required rule:

```
'user_list'  => 'required|array|min:1',

{{ Form::select('user_list[]', $users, null , ['multiple' => 'multiple']) }}
```